SVG morphing on scroll javascript handling

Trying to recreate this javascript scrolling animation - responding to changes in scroll direction and morphing between different transitions

sample of the codebase from the reference https://www.exo.inc/iris
https://jsfiddle.net/0y3eugak/3/

A basic example I've looked over using mousedown events


let rid = null;
// the value of the y coordinate of the point is changing between 134.86 and 177.14
let memory = [134.86, 177.14];
let target = memory[0]; 
let value = memory[1];

//a function that updates that value
function updateValue() {
    let dist = target - value;
    let vel = dist/10;
    value += vel;
    // stopping the animation when the distance between the target and the value is very small
    if (Math.abs(dist) < .01) {
    if(rid){window.cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
    rid = null;
    }
  }  
}

function updatePath() {  
  morphingPath.setAttributeNS(null, "d",`M0,0H47V156L23.5, ${value}L0,156V0z`);
}

function Frame() {
  rid = window.requestAnimationFrame(Frame);
  updateValue();
  updatePath();
}

window.addEventListener(
  "load",
   updatePath,
   false
);

svg.addEventListener(//animate the path on mousedown
  "mousedown",
  function() {
    if (rid) {
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
      rid = null;
    }
    
    memory.reverse();
    target = memory[1];
    Frame();
  },
  false
);
svg{width:50px;}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 46 180"><path id="morphingPath" d="M0,0h47v156L23.5,134.86L0,156V0z" /></svg>



I want to try and replicate this using gsap and scroll --
https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/wvMrEzR
https://codepen.io/japongnet/pen/xxZXWWG

latest example
// gsap.to()... infinity and beyond!
// To learn how to use GSAP, go to greensock.com/get-started

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

var tl = gsap.timeline();
circle = document.getElementById("circle");

tl.to(circle, {
    morphSVG: "#hippo", 
    duration: 1,
    scrollTrigger:{
      trigger:"#v-spacer-1",
      markers:false,
      scrub:true,
      start:"top top",
    }
  }, "+=1")

html
<svg version="1.1"
    id="svg2" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" sodipodi:docname="Domestic_Dromedary_silhouette.svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" 
    viewBox="9 80 800 400" style="enable-background:new 9 80 800 400;" xml:space="preserve">
      <style type="text/css">
         
         .st1{fill:black;}
      </style>

  
  <!--SHAPE #1-->
   <path id="circle" class="st1" d="M490.1,280.649c0,44.459-36.041,80.5-80.5,80.5s-80.5-36.041-80.5-80.5s36.041-80.5,80.5-80.5
      S490.1,236.19,490.1,280.649z"/>
  
   <!--SHAPE #2-->
   <path id="hippo" class="st1" d="M 194 440 L 609 444 L 592 125 L 187 113 Z"/>
  
   <path id="star" class="st1" d="M409.6,198.066l26.833,54.369l60,8.719l-43.417,42.321l10.249,59.758L409.6,335.019
      l-53.666,28.214l10.249-59.758l-43.417-42.321l60-8.719L409.6,198.066z"/>
   </svg>

<div id="v-spacer-1" class="v-spacer">

</div>
<div id="v-spacer-2" class="v-spacer">

</div>


https://codepen.io/BlazgoCompany/pen/OJeqNJR?editors=1010
I believe this is what you are looking for. Theres nothing to change in the CSS and JS but the HTML should be updated as per your needs:

 <!--SHAPE #1-->
   <path id="circle" class="st1" d="M490.1,280.649c0,44.459-36.041,80.5-80.5,80.5s-80.5-36.041-80.5-80.5s36.041-80.5,80.5-80.5
      S490.1,236.19,490.1,280.649z"/>
  
   <!--SHAPE #2-->
   <path id="square" class="st1" d="M 194 440 L 609 444 L 592 125 L 187 113 Z"/>

You can draw your first shape here, copy the path, and paste it into #circle then make another shape and paste it into #square
You can also change the ID's of your shapes based on what shape they are. Just make sure you also change the timeline:
tl.to("#shape-1-id", {
    morphSVG: "#shape-2-id",
    
    //...

  }, "+=1")


This is a good start - but it doesnt match the full bleed example - semi-circle, diagonal cut in the middle -- with the background being an eggshell gradient

Ah ok... I thought that was just an example. Let me edit that codepen

I've edited the codepen, you can use the same link... I'm not sure how to do the gradient but I'll figure out soon... This may help you with doing that.
